Are the user playlists on spotify auto updated?
We all know there are playlists curated by the spotify team. And in the app, we can create our own playlist. In this "self created" playlist (meaning a user creates an empty playlist for himself), we can add one or more spotify curated playlists.
If this is the case, when the corresponding spotify curated list updates with new songs, will the self-created playlist also update with the new songs? Will the songs added via a previous update get chucked off from the self-created playlist?
